# rust/wasm_bindgen: recursive use of an object detected which would lead to unsafe aliasing in rust

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I'm working on my first project with rust/wasm_bindgen and I'm using web_sys to make requests to another service.

I have a number of controllers, like the one below, that get called from js with some request parameters and call one function `send` that makes the request:

```
pub async fn get_some_data(&mut self, req_param: String) -> Result<JsValue, JsValue> {
    let req_param = String::from(req_param);
    let request_endpoint = "some_endpoint";
    let request_body = json!({ "req_param": req_param });
    let json = self.send(request_endpoint.to_string(), request_body.to_string()).await?;
    Ok(json)
}
```

Here is the `send` function:

```
pub async fn send(&mut self, request_endpoint: String, request_body: String) -> Result<JsValue, JsValue> {
    let window = window().ok_or_else(|| JsValue::from_str("Failed to get window object"))?;

    // prepare params ...

    let mut req = RequestInit::new();
    req.method("POST");
    req.mode(RequestMode::Cors);
    req.body(Some(&JsValue::from_str(&request_body.to_string())));

    let request = Request::new_with_str_and_init(&url, &req)?;
    request.headers().set("Content-type", "application/json")?;
    request.headers().set("Accept", "text/plain")?;

    let resp_value = JsFuture::from(window.fetch_with_request(&request)).await?;
    let response: Response = resp_value.dyn_into()?;

    // check API response
    if !response.ok() {
        return Err(JsValue::from_str(&format!("HTTP error response: {}",response.status())));
    }

    // parse API response as JSON and return
    let json = JsFuture::from(response.json()?)
        .await?;
    Ok(json)
}
```

As I made more controllers, now Im getting the error:

`recursive use of an object detected which would lead to unsafe aliasing in rust`

Which, I think, happens because the `send` function is called concurrently.
In fact, if I delay one of the controllers in js with a setTimeout, the error goes away.

How can I make the `send` function handle concurrent requests?

Comment: Nit: `request_body.to_string()` is redundant, `request_body` is already a `String`.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was in one of the codebases I've worked with observed mainly when:

1. an `async` method that had the `&mut self` signature was called before/after another method with either `&mut self` or `&self` was called (concurrent object access).
2. in TS/JS code a rust wasm function is called inside another rust wasm function, e.g.:

```js
import { f1, f2 } from '../wasm-utils.js'

// where f1 returns a wasm object X that f2 takes as an argument
f2(f1())
```

In your case the 1) case likely applies, maybe the `send` method is called by the JS code at the same time as another piece of code calls this or another method of the object that `self` references.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.